# Using sed and arithmetic in the same line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

So the following variables

`COMPRESSED` and `UNCOMPRESSED`

hold an alphanumeric string (they store file sizes, so strings like 4K, 2500MB, etc). I would like to do some algebra (divide) on them while using sed to remove the letters (K, MB, etc) in order to actually be able to divide.  like so:

```
RATIO=$((COMPRESSED| sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g' / UNCOMPRESSED | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g'))
```

No clue if this is possible. I just wanna avoid clogging my script with variables. thanks!

**edit:**

input :

`./prog2.sh file.txt` <--- this file will be compressed in the script. `COMPRESSED` holds the compressed size and `UNCOMPRESSED` holds the uncompressed size. of the file

expected output:

`ratio: $RATIO` <--- whatever the value of `COMPRESSED/UNCOMPRESSED` is (for example 0.55 or 1/2 or whatever that number comes out to be"

Say `COMPRESSED` = 2500MB and `UNCOMPRESSED` = 43000MB. I want to divide these numbers, but in order to do so i would have to remove the `MB` at the end of the strings, leaving me with `2500` and `4300` I am trying to do so with sed in the algebraic sequence as to avoid making new variables.

Comment: Please add sample Input and expected output in your post with CODE TAGS too.

Comment: Add multiple examples for COMPRESSED and UNCOMPRESSED to your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  done

Comment: @Cyrus just did it

Comment: @jrdev, add 3 simple things. 1- Sample Input(file). 2- Sample expected output file and 3rd- what you have tried with all your requirements/conditions.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the input/output files arent necessary they dont change. only the file sizes change upon compression . i hope i made it more clear i apoligze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the divide `compressed` and `un-compressed` values then following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -v comp="2500MB"  -v un_comp="43000MB" 'BEGIN{print (comp+0)/(un_comp+0)}'
```

In case you have bash variables and you want to use them into `awk` then use following:

```
compress="2500MB"
un_compress="4300MB"
awk -v comp="$COMP"  -v un_comp="$un_compress" 'BEGIN{print (comp+0)/(un_comp+0)}'
```

Or in case you want to divide vice versa uncompressed values by compressed values then you could change only divide part in above code then.

Comment: it works! in my case they were bash variables and it ran perfectly thanks!